# Plotting a sympy plot for simultanous ODE solutions

Tags: sympy

```
g, d = symbols("g d", cls=Function)

T, G= symbols("T G")

system = [Eq( d(t).diff(t), - d(t)/T), Eq( g(t).diff(t), - G*g(t) + d(t)/T )]

ics = {d(0): 1, g(0): 0}

e = sym.dsolve(system, [g(t), d(t)], ics=ics)
```

is the code I am using to find solutions. How do I plot the functions across time with G and T as constants ?
I tried using lambdify function, but pops up an error.

```
lmbd_sol = lambdify(t, e.rhs)
```

Comment: You need to substitute values for `T` and `G`.

Comment: where should I add the values ?

Comment: You can use e.g. `esubs = e.subs({T: 1, G:2})`.